# Come tradurre in italiano la frase tedesca "Das geozentrische Weltbild wurde durch das heliozentrische abgelöst"?

Tags: translation

La mia lingua madre è l'italiano, ma non riesco a capire come tradurre la seguente frase:

> "*Das geozentrische Weltbild wurde durch das heliozentrische
>   abgelöst*"

Ho pensato:

> "*La geocentrica concezione del mondo è stata sostituita  ____?____  l'eliocentrica*"

Chiaramente ho un problema con la preposizione "*durch*", se ho studiato bene in questo caso questa preposizione si lega con il verbo "*ablösen*", ho anche consultato due dizionari ([hier](http://dict.leo.org/itde/index_de.html#/search=abl%C3%B6sen&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) und [hier](http://deit.dict.cc/?s=abl%C3%B6sen)), ma non ho trovato niente. 
Anche se non sono sicuro ho pensato alle seguenti:

> "*La geocentrica concezione del mondo è stata sostituita con quella eliocentrica*"
>
> "*La geocentrica concezione del mondo è stata sostituita da quella eliocentrica*"

La seconda soluzione mi sembra funzionare bene in quanto è esplicito il complemento d'agente che in una forma passiva (dai miei studi) è reso dalla preposizione "*da ____*"; desidero un chiarimento, ringrazio a priori!

Comment: Essendo praticamente bilingue it-de confermo la risposta approvata, ma penso che la domanda si compone di due parti (interpretazione del testo tedesco e generazione del testo italiano), di cui la prima dovrebbe stare su german.stackexchange.com, non su italian.stackexchange.com

Comment: @WalterTross, avevo postato la questione (in tedesco) su german.stackexchange.com e stavano votando per chiuderla perchè per loro era più adatto italian.stackexchange.com (senza interpretazione alcuna da spartire)..

Comment: Non trovo la domanda su German SE, ma posso immaginare il motivo per i voti di chiusura: la domanda non è stata divisa nelle sue due parti.

Comment: @WalterTross, essendo alle prime armi in tedesco non sapevo come fare a modificare adeguatamente la questione ergo l'ho eliminata.. se potete aiutarmi su come fare mi va bene separarla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Io direi:

> La visione geocentrica della Terra è stata / fu sostituita da quella eliocentrica

Da quanto so / [ho trovato](http://www.italotedesco.de/Texte/BREVE%20GRAMMATICA%20TEDESCO%20_2_.pdf) (pagina 16), *durch* può introdurre il complemento d'agente, ma inteso come un mezzo:

> Die Tür wurde durch einen Stoß geöffnet / La porta fu
>   aperta da un colpo.

Inoltre, *abgelöst werden durch* sembra essere una espressione idiomatica, che ho trovato in [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaissance), su [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/abgel%C3%B6st+werden+durch.html) e su [linguee.it](http://www.linguee.it/tedesco-italiano/traduzione/abgel%C3%B6st+durch.html), che linka a un documento ufficiale della Commissione Europea, tradotto con "sostituita da"/ "superseded by". Io mi fiderei delle traduzioni europee :)

P.S.: In inglese è "to make way (for)", ma in italiano non direi "lasciare spazio (a)", almeno in questo caso

Comment: wunderbare Antwort! Danke! Non sapevo che durch potesse introdurre anche un complemento d'agente, davvero curioso.. grazie mille per fonti ;)

Comment: @mle di niente! Ho dato un'occhiata alle tue domande su German.SE, posso chiederti che risorse usi per studiare?

Comment: frequento un corso di lingua tedesca presso Heidelberg Pädagogium, i testi che uso (di riferimento) da livello a livello sono http://www.schubert-verlag.de/begegnungen.php e http://www.schubert-verlag.de/erkundungen_info.php?PHPSESSID=5addece89864d019c3069aae5ff79771 ... inoltre l'insegnante fornisce altro materiale (tanto materiale). Purtroppo i testi sono si buoni ma per il mio modo di studiare sono scarsi nella grammatica allora consulto altri siti come http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de o http://www.canoo.net/ o https://deutsch.lingolia.com/it/ e altri che non ricordo ;)

Comment: @mle anch'io avevo cominciato con quel libro l'anno scorso :) E anche a me mancava la grammatica, ti capisco.

Comment: Un altro buon candidato è *soppiantata da*.